# Where am I taking this to?

Tags: prepositions, questions

- *Where are you going?*
- *Where are you ***from***?*

In the first sentence, we don't need to use a preposition for ***Where*** (question word) but in the other sentences we need to use prepositions, why?

Comment: _Where are you?_ means something different, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't related to "where"; it's related to the verb "to be". When you answer the question, you still need to use the preposition. I'm **from** ...

In the first sentence, if you change the verb to "come", you will need to use the preposition "from" again.

> Where are you coming **from**?
> I'm coming **from** the kitchen.

So, it also depends on the verb you are using.